# Capturing HTTP requests done by a loading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, http

Please be patient, because it will take me a relatively long explanation in order to tell you what I need.

I'm building a web development framework and one of the entities I need to deal with are `components`. A `component` is a part of a web page. May be a graph or a table or any other thing. A component is loaded in a page by a call to a javascript method like

```
EMERALD.component.show('some.namespace.component_name','dom_area');
```

This would tell the framework to get the contents of this component `some.namespace.component_name` and load them into `dom_area`, a HTML element with id `dom_area`.

The simplest of all components is a static piece of HTML code. And this piece of HTML may contain elements who create new HTTP requests, like references to CSS files, images... whatever.

A component is stored in a directory structure. Using the component `some.namespace.component_name` mentioned above as an example, it would be stored like this

```
assets/
  |
  -- components/
       |
       --some/
          |
          -- namespace/
               |
               -- component_name/
                    |
                    -- config.json
                    |
                    -- css/
                    |   |
                    |   -- layout.css
                    |
                    -- images/
                    |    |
                    |    -- some_image.jpg
                    -- page.html
```

Things are very simple, indeed. The KISS principle is one of my paradigms. The `EMERALD.component.show('some.namespace.component_name','dom_area');`, after a few things, loads the HTML fragment `page.html`.

My problem is: **When `page.html` is loaded, if it loads `layout.css` and `some_image.jpg`, the HTTP requests are not going to be loaded, unless they are referenced absolutely, and this is not convenient to me.**

What I would like to do is have a `page.html` like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout.css">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="thering"></div>
</div>
```

and a `layout.css` like

```
.thering {
    height: 385px;
    background: #000 url('thering.png');
    border-color: #222 !important;
}
```

And then capture the HTTP requests of `layout.css` (in `page.html`) and `thering.png` (in `layout.css`) and append the right path so that they may be loaded correctly.

I've tried a few things, but none worked. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are ok with a one page solution, you can use [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) element. Then the absolute value is there just not required for every line you write.

[`Require.js`](http://requirejs.org/) is perfect solution for your needs in the future.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Add Base</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var base = document.createElement('base');
    base.href = 'https://sub.domain.com/absolute/path/to/';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(base);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not a "magical way", for sure. And my references were right. You just don't get what I mean. What I said was I intended only to mention the file, with no absolute paths, and let the framework locate the file. This is the reason why I wrote just the name of the file.

Comment: But I got what you mean and your solution is perfect to me. I made it a bit shorter because I use jQuery, not pure Javascript. But thanks!

Comment: I'm just surprised you don't know what I mean with KISS. "Keep it Simple, Stupid" is a largely known paradigm: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keep_It_Simple 

It has nothing to do with magic, as you (ironically) said. It just a way to keep things very simple. And programmers, as you surely know, absorb complexity in the code, in order to make things simple for the users.

Comment: Lol, I realized that now that's why I'm editing the answer, and you are very welcome, sir. :)

Comment: My problem here was the fact I was retriveing all this component files from my /index.html. Then the base path, before your solution, was /, not the base path of `page.html`. When you use `jQuery.load` you are not changing base path. This idea of setting a base in the header was great. I didn't know this was possible and you helped me a lot!

Comment: That's great! I also added a suggestion that you should look into [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/). It is **exactly** what you need as your site grows.